# Ngrx createReducer migrating from earlier version

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, redux, ngrx

I am having difficulties in migrating the reducer code to use createReducer(), specially for the default case.

```
export function reducer(
    state: { [key: string]: any },
    action: FormActions
): { [key: string]: any } {
    const newState = _.cloneDeep(state);

    switch (action.type) {
        case FormActionTypes.UpdateValue: {
            return fieldUpdateReducer(newState, action as UpdateValue);
        }

        case RESET_WIZARD:
        case WizardActionTypes.ResetWizard: {
            return {};
        }

        default: {
            return fromForm.reducer(state, action as FormActions);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to change it like below, but the unit test for the default case is failing. I am here trying to call other reducer in case of default option.

```
export const createClusterFormReducer = createReducer(
    (state, action) => fromForm.reducer(state, action),
    on(updateValue, (state: { [key: string]: any }, action: Action) => {
        const newState = _.cloneDeep(state);
        return fieldUpdateReducer(newState, action);
    }),
    on(resetWizard, (state, action) => {
        return {};
    }),
    on(wizardActionsResetWizard, (state, action) => {
        return {};
    })
);
export function reducer(
    state: { [key: string]: any },
    action: Action
): { [key: string]: any } {
    return createClusterFormReducer(state, action);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no default case with `createReducer`, but there are some options to support this.

You can create a [higher order reducer](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/1956#issuecomment-526720340) though.

Or add other `on` methods by using the spread operator.

export const createClusterFormReducer = createReducer(
(state, action) => fromForm.reducer(state, action),
on(updateValue, (state: { [key: string]: any }, action: Action) => {
const newState = _.cloneDeep(state);
return fieldUpdateReducer(newState, action);
}),
on(resetWizard, (state, action) => {
return {};
}),
...otherOnMethods
);

Maybe the simplest is to create a meta reducer.

```
export function reducer(
    state: { [key: string]: any },
    action: Action
): { [key: string]: any } {
    const newState = createClusterFormReducer(state, action);
    if(newState === state) {
       return otherReducer(state,action)
    }
    return newState;
}
```